# Как получить ответ от принимающей стороны при отправке почты через mail()?

Tags: php

Через крон настроена автоматическая массовая рассылка писем пользователям каждое первое число нового месяца.

Почему-то в прошлый раз была замечена ситуация, что практически всем у кого почта находится только на mail.ru/list.ru - письма не дошли, хотя они точно были отправлены через функцию `mail()`.

В связи с этим вопрос - можно как-нибудь получить и обработать ответ удаленного сервера с причиной по которой письмо не было доставлено?

Comment: http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html и https://github.com/hbattat/verifyEmail

Answer (score 1):

Пример из документации

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Вон там, где From и Reply-To указываете свой email и в общем случае на него будут приходить отлупы от почтовых серверов, если им что-то не понравилось